# Doing series of actions without blocking UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to do a series of actions and simultaneously depend on exception it throw or doesn't throw any exception update my UI, how can I achieve something like this?

I've already tried making new thread for each step but it doesn't wait until one of steps ends and it writes fail message always, using Thread.Join() didn't help either because it blocks UI thread too...

Comment: Which .Net version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Put the code you want to execute in background thread in `DoWork` handler and code of updating UI in `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

In case you want to update GUI in between from `DoWork` handler, you can queue it on UI dispatcher like this -

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
           // Update GUI here.
        }, null);
```

Comment: This answer is the correct one up to Net 4.0. As of Net 4.5 you can use the Async Await pattern. a document describing it can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957