# upload files using php post - freezes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a php script combined with C# to upload files from a folder in Windows onto a webserver directory. It works, however, when the uploading begins, the application freezes.

```
private void submitExam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // loop through and upload our sound bits
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\wav", "*.wav", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string soundBit in files)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
        byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("http://website.com/uploadFiles.php", "POST", soundBit);
    }

    processing f2 = new processing();
    f2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

In the C# application, when the submit button is clicked, the uploading begins and it shows a new form page which displays a message saying the files are being uploaded. The problem I'm having with this is that when the submit button is pressed, the `processing` form doesn't show for about 10 seconds or so until the uploading is finished or nearly finished.

Is there any way to show the processing page while simultaneously uploading the files without any freezing of the application?

Comment: Try this control: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx EDIT: what you're basically looking for is an asynchronous way to upload the file, then get notified that it's done uploading. There are a lot of ways to do it, just search "asp.net async file upload"

Comment: @JesseSmith, thanks for your suggestion, however, I'm not using ASP, rather this is a desktop application.

Comment: Ah! Granted as @Ralph said, this problem is caused by blocking the UI thread -- the end result will still be some form of asynchrony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application is freezing because your upload operation is blocking the main UI thread that needs to always be kept in a state where its run loop is *always* running.

You also need to make sure that when the upload operation completes that you update your UI on the main thread.

The main thread also sometimes called the UI thread is the thread that your Windows Form app uses to handle user input, respond to events, update UI controls, etc.

The freezing behavior is because your upload operation takes around 10 seconds to completely upload the file and therefore your app can't respond until this process is done.  If the upload took 20 minutes, your app would freeze for twenty minutes.

See this post for more information about how to avoid this problem: [Doing series of actions without blocking UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545757/doing-series-of-actions-without-blocking-ui-thread)

Comment: Wonderful! I honestly didn't know this existed. Added it and it works as it should. Thank you very much for sharing.

Comment: @Spencer You are welcome, please consider marking my answer as "answered".

Comment: I certainly will - have to wait another 3 minutes before I can accept it. Cheers!